# Only show SQL results from users with exact three entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT * 
FROM PlanData 
WHERE GeneralEventCode = 'VM' 
  AND AirlineCode = 'LH' 
  AND DateStart > '2019-05-01' 
  AND UserHomeBaseAirportCode = 'FRA'
```

In this table I have also the field `UserId`. I would like to get only results, if a `UserId` has exact 3 entries in that table.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you mean three entries that match your conditions or three entries in general?

Answer (score 1):

You need 1 more condition in the WHERE clause, to select only `UserId`s with 3 entries:

```
SELECT * FROM PlanData 
where 
  GeneralEventCode='VM' 
  and AirlineCode='LH' 
  and DateStart>'2019-05-01' 
  and UserHomeBaseAirportCode='FRA'
  and UserId IN (
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM PlanData 
    GROUP BY UserId 
    HAVING Count(*) = 3
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  The following assumes that you mean three rows that match your conditions:

```
SELECT pd.*
FROM (SELECT pd.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as cnt
      FROM PlanData pd
      WHERE GeneralEventCode = 'VM' and
            AirlineCode='LH' and
            DateStart > '2019-05-01' and 
            UserHomeBaseAirportCode = 'FRA'
    ) pd
WHERE cnt = 3;
```

If you mean three rows of any sort, then:

```
SELECT pd.*
FROM (SELECT pd.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as cnt
      FROM PlanData pd
     ) pd
WHERE GeneralEventCode = 'VM' and
      AirlineCode='LH' and
      DateStart > '2019-05-01' and 
      UserHomeBaseAirportCode = 'FRA' and
      cnt = 3;
```